VBA code to prevent certain cell range from being edited but can still delete rows when needed
I have a shared excel sheet that is essentially a table where it should not go beyond column X. I found this VBA code to make it so that anything from range Y1:XFD1048576 cannot have any information or data added to it, but now I cannot delete any rows in the table when needed. How do I fix this?
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range(“Y1:XFD1048576”),Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub

I tried finding ways to edit the code but to no avail. Haven’t really been able to find anything for this specific problem.

Maybe use data validation (text length = 0) to prevent unwanted editing of cells outside the table. You could also hide the columns in question.

If this is just a temporary requirement. If you open the workbook and DO NOT enable the macro then it will not prevent you from deleting a row. Or you can remove the macro at any time in VBA editor and return it after deleting the required rows.

This might do what you need:
The modified code now checks if the the cells being changed are entire rows (i.e. you're deleting or adding a row) and if it is, does not perform the undo.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("Y:XFD"), Target) Is Nothing _
      And Not Target.EntireRow.Address = Target.Address Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub

